# Как можно реализовать анимацию на сайте?

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация, css-animation, svg-animation

**Всем привет!**
Задался я вопросом создания анимации некоего планшета который состоит из 3 частей.

- Элемент 1 - это корпус
- Элемент 2 - это картинка некоего "кода"
- Элемнты 3 - это картинка интерфейса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Анимация:
Сначала все три элемнты складываются вместе в один будто целый планшет
Когда сайт открылся тогда наверх поднимаются 2 и 3 элемента и слегка пульсируют над элементом 1

Значит как правильнее создать эту анимацию?
Какие есть способы ? 
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: а покажите что вы пытались делать?

Comment: Ничего пока ведь не знаю как это реализовать если перед вами была такая задача вы б что сделали ?

Comment: тут надо отдельные слои-компоненты , хоть в svg хоть в png ...расположены друг на друге ..и отцентрировано идеально ...

Comment: вообще смысла закрывать вопрос нету, так как подобная реализация не обсуждалась на stackoverflow ни разу

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, вот так можно https://codepen.io/St1myL/pen/vrNRPm?editors=1100

Comment: @Arthur  нового ты мне не открыл ...я умею пользоваться css3 в полном объёме , stackoverflow это источник информации , если нету желания отвечать по вопросу его можно просто проигнорировать ...на  z-index я делал ещё лет так ....6 назад ... тут дело не только в нём ..

Comment: Спасибо за пример

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, я рад за тебя=)

Comment: @Arthur  тут вопрос о том как привязать scroll к тому примеру что ты показал

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, а `scroll` зачем? Вроде анимацию нужно было, да и всё

Comment: @Arthur  я это на apple видел - когда они презентовали 5айфон ..так они смарт свой до мельчайших частичек раскладывали а по скролу сворачивали опять в смарт - очень эффектно смотрится

Comment: @Arthur  по крайней мере если бы я знал хотя бы jQuery на столько хорошо я бы это сделал бы на этом событие ...как тот чувак с youtube